# n-queens Prolog visualizing by special letters

Tags: prolog, n-queens

I want to visualize n-queens problem in Prolog.

Like this,

```
1? -queen(1,2,5).
===================
# Q # # #
# # # Q #
Q # # # #
# # Q # #
# # # # Q
===================
===================
# Q # # #
# # # # Q
# # Q # #
Q # # # #
# # # Q #
===================

Total Output is 2
true.
```

So, I want to use this N-queens in Prolog.

```
solution(_, []).
solution(N, [X/Y|Others]) :-
    solution(N, Others),
    between(1, N, Y),
    noattack(X/Y, Others).

noattack(_,[]).
noattack(X/Y, [X1/Y1 | Others]) :-
    Y =\= Y1,
    Y1-Y =\= X1-X,
    Y1-Y =\= X-X1,
    noattack( X/Y, Others).

template(N, L) :-
    findall(I/_, between(1,N,I), L).
```

This make like this output.

```
?- N=6, template(N, L), solution(N, L).
N = 6,
L = [1/5, 2/3, 3/1, 4/6, 5/4, 6/2] ;
N = 6,
L = [1/4, 2/1, 3/5, 4/2, 5/6, 6/3] ;
N = 6,
L = [1/3, 2/6, 3/2, 4/5, 5/1, 6/4] ;
N = 6,
L = [1/2, 2/4, 3/6, 4/1, 5/3, 6/5] ;
```

**queen(X, Y, N)** is

(X, Y) is queen's position.

(N) is queen's degree.

I want to visualize this N-queens Problem by

find L's component and visualizing component.

For example, if u find out L = [...,3/4,...]

print out this # is N-1 times, and Q is fourth.

Here is Error-prone code in Prolog.

```
queen(X,Y,N):-
    position(X,Y), %consummate this L list and bring to Ls
    print_queen( Ls , N).
```

I don't know how to represent this

```
position(X,Y).    

print_queen(Ls, N).

queen(X,Y,N).
```

part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to provide you a **SWI-Prolog** solution for the formatted output you requested.

To print a line of size `N` with the queen on position `Col` using '#' and 'Q', you could use:

```
Col1 is Col - 1, format('~|~`#t~*+Q~`#t~*|~n',[Col1, N]).
```

See the [documentation](http://swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2) for details about `format/2`. E.g.:

```
?- Col = 3, N = 8, Col1 is Col-1, format('~|~`#t~*+Q~`#t~*|~n',[Col1,N]).
##Q#####
```

Now, assuming your solution is in this form `[1/Q1, 2/Q2, 3/Q3, ..., N/QN]`, you can use `forall/2` to satisfy `format/2` for every queen (element in your list):

```
print_queens(Queens, N):-
    forall(member(_/Col, Queens),
           ( Col1 is Col-1, format('~|~`#t~*+Q~`#t~*|~n',[Col1,N]) )
          ).
```

Using the above predicate:

```
?- print_queens([1/3,2/1,3/4,4/5,5/3,6/6], 6).
##Q###
Q#####
###Q##
####Q#
##Q###
#####Q
true.
```

Later edit (after clarifications from comments):
In order to print all the solutions for the `N`-queens given a fixed position for one of them:

```
queen(X, Y, N):-
    template(N, L),    % Build the template of the solution
    member(X/Y, L),    % Unify given value for Y with its corresponding variable in L
    !,                 % Green cut

    % Count solutions while printing them
    findall(s, (solution(N, L), print_queens(L, N)), All),

    % Print total number of solutions
    length(All, Len),
    format('Total Output is ~w.~n', [Len]).
```

Comment: Thanks u very much. So, i want to position this queen by position(X, Y). and read this position and input to print_queen().  I'm sorry to this rude attitude.:(

Comment: Is this what you want: to solve the `N`-queens problem with a fixed queen?  `queen(X,Y,N):-template(N,L), member(X/Y,L), solution(N,L), print_queens(L,N).`

Comment: This part from your question is not clear at all: "`position(X,Y), %consummate this L list and bring to Ls`". What is the purpose of `position/2` and how do you expect it to influence `Ls` if `Ls` is not among its arguments?

Comment: Or if `print_queen(Ls, N)` should print the `N`th queen from list `Ls`, you can use `nth1/3`: `print_queen(Ls,N):-nth1(N,Ls,Row/Col), format(....).`

Comment: I want to get this output. My input is just  `queen(1,2,5).`. and My output is just `//#Q###
###Q#
Q####
##Q##
####Q//

//#Q###
####Q
##Q##
Q####
###Q#//

Total Output is 2
true.`

Comment: `queen(X, Y, N) :- template(N, L), member(X/Y, L), !, findall(s, (solution(N, L), print_queens(L, N)), All), length(All, Len), format('Total Output is ~w.~n', [Len]).`

Comment: I do like this but i get some errors,like this `2 ?- queen(1,3,6).
ERROR: '<meta-call>'/1: Undefined procedure: print_queens/2
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         print_queen/2`

Comment: Change `print_queens` to `print_queen` then.

Comment: Nice!! Last... this can't count Total Output. I got `false`. If Output is just one, It doesn't have any error.

Comment: If `findall/3` succeeds, then there is no reason for `length/2` or `format/2` to fail, so you should not get `false`. Please compare the code provided in the answer with yours and see if there are any differences.